# How to identify Client Application Coordinate or point

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests, mainframe

We have a mainframe application which is in client machine . we connect to that application using terminal emulator . we are planing to use coded ui automation tool to automate that application . till now i am able to send text and capture text from that application . To achieve that i used point which is basically screen coordinate but i need to find application coordinate .

Could anybody help me in this .

Comment: If what you are trying to do is get the application position on the screen then you could try this: `this.Top` and `this.Left`. That will give you the top and the left position of the application, this is for windows forms.

Comment: @maam27 we are trying to get the coordinate of application rather then monitor screen coordinate . if i change the size of application still those coordinate must work . now i have to set the size of the application to maximum when i restore it , i unable to get desired result . that's why i want to find a way to identify application coordinate .

Comment: Is this really about [coded-ui-tests]? Please give more details of what you have tried and what actually happened.

Comment: You need to do a lot of clarification to your question. Emulators sometimes have their own macro language for doing things like you want, but not all, and we don't know which you have. Other than that, how is it relevant that a particular window happens to be a terminal emulation?